# Exclude multiples dirs with the command tree Where-Object

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to know how to put multiple arguments in the `Where-Object`.
I would like to exclude multiple folders when I use the tree command.
I tried several ways but none worked.

```
tree /F src /a | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*__pycache__" -or $_ -notlike "*migrations"} > tree.txt

tree /F src /a | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*__pycache__|*migrations"} > tree.txt
```

Comment: change `-or` to `-and`.

Comment: This would help you exclude the parent folder if the condition is matched but it wouldn't exclude the files inside the excluded folder. Those would still be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logic problem. "-or -notlike b" allows "-like a".  Do something like -not (this -or that), a handy idiom to know.  Also, the `|` symbol is not a wildcard character, but you can use it with -notmatch as regex.

```
'a','b' | ? { $_ -notlike '*a*' -or $_ -notlike '*b*' }

a
b


'a','b' | ? { $_ -notlike '*a*|*b*' }

a
b


'a','b' | ? { -not ($_ -like '*a*' -or $_ -like '*b*' ) }

# no result


'a','b' | ? { $_ -notmatch 'a|b' }

# no result
```